# Proof that this sequence of functions converges pointwise.

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence

Consider the sequence of functions $f_{1}, f_{2}, \ldots$ on $[0,1]$ defined by $f_{k}(x) = x^{k}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that this sequence converges pointwise to the following function:
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 0 & 0 \leq x < 1 \\
                       1 & x = 1
\end{cases}
$$

Scrap: 
Case 1: $0 \leq x < 1$
$$
|f_{k}(x) - f(x)| \\
|f_{k}(x) - 0| \\
|f_{k}(x)| \\
|x^{k}| \\
|x|^{k} \\
x^{k} 
$$
So
$$
x^{k} < \epsilon \\
log(x^{k}) < log(\epsilon) \\
k*log(x) < log(\epsilon) \\
k > \frac{log(\epsilon)}{log(x)}
$$

Case 2: x = 1
$$
|f_{k}(x) - f(x)| \\
|1^{k} - 1| \\
|1 - 1| \\
|0| \\
0 \\
$$
So
$$
0 < \epsilon 
$$
This is already true by definition.

Proof:

Let $x \in [0,1]$

Let $\epsilon > 0$

Choose $N = \frac{log(\epsilon)}{log(x)}$

Then for every $k > N$ we have:

Case 1: $0 \leq x < 1$
$$
|f_{k}(x) - f(x)| \\
|f_{k}(x) - 0| \\
|f_{k}(x)| \\
|x^{k}| \\
|x|^{k} \\
x^{k} 
$$

But I am now stuck, since I do not how to properly rewrite this to use the chosen k which seems to be correct in the scrap paper (my equality seems to not be correct).

Comment: When in doubt, go back to the exponential form: $x^k = e^{k\log(x)}$.

Comment: Wow that I didn't see that, thank you so much! Looking at it for over an hour now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to invoke logarithms here. If $0\leqslant x<1$ then $x^n-x^{n-1}=x^n(1-x)\geqslant 0$, so the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is decreasing. As the sequence is bounded below, it converges to some $y\in\mathbb R$. Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=y$. Then
$$
xy = x\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n = \lim_{n\to\infty} x^{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=y.
$$
As $xy=y$, we have $(x-1)y=0$, so $y=0$.